# Donvier ice cream maker - inserting the bucket

Tags: equipment, ice-cream

Recently I bought a Donvier 1 pint ice cream maker on Ebay.  When I figured out how to put the rim on the chill recepticle it didn't seem that hard.  When the ice cream didn't freeze I did some research.  The instructions didn't tell you enough and I still have a few questions.  I hope my experience will help others.

Although I got the rim on the bucket when I took it out of the box, I couldn't get it to fit down when the bucket was frozen.  One person suggested putting it on before you put it in the freezer.  Will this hurt the rim?

Comment: Hello Nancy, and welcome to our site. You may be accustomed to discussion forums on the Internet; our format is somewhat different. We only accept one question per "thread" and that question has to be quite focused and objectively answerable. So for example, asking about "pointers" or "tips" doesn't work well with our system. I had to edit your text to leave only one question. Of the three that I removed, the first and last cannot be answered on our site. The one about the length of chilling is possibly a duplicate to https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/52189, you can possibly...

Comment: ... ask it separately, then your text would have to make it clear why it is not the same as the old question and why it needs separate answers.